# UITableView - reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here's my scenario:

I have a cell with a label. When I first load the cell, the model may not have the data needed for the label...so when I find out (via a delegate call) that the model just got the label data or the label data has changed, I can then reload the particular cell. The reason I need to reload the cell (rather than just setting the label's text) is that it's height could change based on whether the label has text or not.

Here's what I'm doing in my delegate call:

```
- (void)modelLabelDataDidChangeForModel:(NSString *)modelId
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForModel:modelId]; // Local method to get index path.
     MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        [self.table beginUpdates];
        [cell updateMostImportantContent];
        [self.table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.table endUpdates];
    }
}
```

I'm getting a crash (`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]`) at `endUpdates` because it says the number of rows after the update doesn't match the number of rows before the update (since I didn't explicitly add/remove any rows during the update block; I just reloaded 1 row).

So this makes me think that the model probably has 2 changes going on at the same time: the label data is changing for 1 item (hence my delegate call), but then also an item is being added to the model (hence the crash).

So this makes me think, how can I tell whether I need to call `reloadData` or whether I can just reload 1 cell with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]`?

Do I have to track that with the model myself, or is there something I can do with the table view to determine this and avoid the crash?

My goal is to be efficient: call `reloadData` when I need to, but call `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:@[indexPath]` when I can.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

*When this method is called in an animation block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods, it behaves similarly to deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. The indexes that UITableView passes to the method are specified in the state of the table view prior to any updates. This happens regardless of ordering of the insertion, deletion, and reloading method calls within the animation block.*

It doesn't appear to me that you need or require this sort of call or method. You are updating a single index.
If you do want to update multiple indexes you should arrange this differently by creating an array of the indexes you wish to update, then perhaps use the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` series at the completion of your data update.

Comment: I was getting the crash when I just used beingUpdates / endUpdates as well too...so I tried just using the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths approach, but it didn't fix it. So I tried combining them. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `-endUpdates` method forces `UITableView` to recalculate heights for all visible cells. Before it does that, it verifies consistency of currently displayed data and calls

```
 - numberOfSectionsInTableView:
 - tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

methods of its `dataSource`.
When you don't call `-reloadData`, `UITableView` relies that data it gathered before (e.g. number of sections, number of rows in section) is the same.

When it is not the same, you get assertion and crash.

To make your data consistent with the state of the `UITableView`, you have to delete/insert the cells on index paths where objects were gone or newly appeared, within the `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` block.

Comment: I understand what the crash means and why it's happening, but I'm wondering how I can tell whether to reload the table or just reload a cell. Even without using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, the crash still happens because the model gets out of sync with the table. How can I tell if the model is out of sync with the current data?

Comment: One of the possible ways to keep your tableView in sync with the model is to use NSFetchedResultsController. It will report all changes to your data set that is currently shown in the table, and you will be able to insert/delete rows with animation.

Comment: Right, but my model isn't backed by a core data entity (and I can't move it to core data right now for lots of reasons that aren't worth delving into right now).

Comment: Imagine you have data set [A, B, C], and on the next update you have a data set [A, B, D]. If you have no possibility to know whether C object has been deleted and D object has been added (e.g. to reload row at index 2), then the only way is to always use reloadData. If you have possibility to know that, then you can also know whether you had data set [A, B, C] and now you have data set [A, B, C, D] (e.g. to insert row at index 3). Same for deletion. In this case, last paragraph of the answer will solve the problem.